# How do I filter by a CQL column not in the PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have following table in Cassandra:

```
create table ibc.my_table
(
    my_key_1 uuid,
    my_key_2 uuid,
    my_key_3 uuid,
    end_timestamp timestamp,
    locked boolean,
    maximum_duration_minutes int,
    maximum_participant_count int,
    owner_id uuid,
    start_timestamp timestamp,
    status_code text,
    primary key ((my_key_1, my_key_2), my_key_3)
)
```

This query works:

```
select * from my_table
where my_key_1=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
    AND my_key_2=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
```

but this one - not:

```
select * from my_table
where my_key_1=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
    AND my_key_2=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
    AND owner_id=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
```

> Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and
> thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this
> query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING

I don't want to use ALLOW FILTERING because of performance. I also can't make owner_id as a part of primary key.

Do I have another option in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would use a [Secondary Index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html).  Typically, you would have to be careful over performance with Secondary Indexes, just as you would with using `ALLOW FILTERING`.

But in this particular case, it's ok.  Your query's `WHERE` clause is filtering on both of your partition keys (`my_key_1` and `my_key_2`...*terrible names, BTW*).  By specifying both partition keys, you're ensuring that the query can be served by a single node, and the index will simply help Cassandra find the matching entries *inside* the partition.

To add the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON ibc.my_table(owner_id);
```

Then re-run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ibc.my_table
WHERE my_key_1=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
  AND my_key_2=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
  AND owner_id=3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6 ;

 my_key_1                             | my_key_2                             | my_key_3                             | end_timestamp | locked | maximum_duration_minutes | maximum_participant_count | owner_id                             | start_timestamp                 | status_code
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------+--------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------
 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6 | 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6 | aff2206e-fc3f-4ab4-9918-38da59c1f31d |          null |  False |                     null |                      null | 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6 | 2022-03-11 00:19:49.699000+0000 |           5

(1 rows)
```

This should perform well, as long as the index is always used with the *complete* partition key.